# Filter command history by folder they were executed in?

Tags: zsh

I know shell history doesn't keep track of the folder the commands were executed in but I think it would be really useful to be able to output the history for a particular folder by using a flag like `history --local` for example.

I often jump from project to project which use very similar commands but have different destination host for ssh or environment variable...

Is there any way to achieve that –preferably using zsh?

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can set PROMPT_COMMAND to something like the following:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history | tail -n1 >> .$USER.history'
```

It will save each command to a file in the current directory.

For an alternative approach (replacing `cd` with a command that changes where history is saved), see http://www.compbiome.com/2010/07/bash-per-directory-bash-history.html.